# Compass does not see a local gem installed by Bundler

Tags: rubygems, bundler, compass-sass

In my Gemfile I have:

```
gem 'stitch', :path => "/Users/myname/stitch-css"
```

When I run 'bundle install' I see:

```
Using stitch (0.1.3) from source at /Users/myname/stitch-css
```

But when I run 'compass watch' I get this error:

```
LoadError on line ["36"] of /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb: no such file to load -- stitch
```

Of course, I can install the gem using:

```
gem install stitch
```

...and the gem then loads fine for Compass, but not from my local version - the path in my Gemfile is ignored

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `bundle exec compass watch` instead.

Comment: Works. It weirdly tells me to install `rb-fsevent` (which is installed), but it works - thanks!